# Applying Borel-Cantelli to $\limsup$ of subsequences of fair coin tossing

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $H_i$ be the event that a fair coin is heads, and consider infinite, independent, fair coin tossing. Prove or disprove the following two implications:

$\cap_{m=1}^\infty \cup_{n=m}^\infty\big(\cap_{i=1}^{\log_2(n\log_2(n^2))}H_{n\log_2(n^2)+i}\big) \subseteq \cap_{m=1}^\infty \cup_{n=m}^\infty\big(\cap_{i=1}^{\log_2(n)}H_{n+i}\big)$

$\cap_{m=1}^\infty \cup_{n=m}^\infty\big(\cap_{i=1}^{\log_2(n^2)}H_{n^2+i}\big) \subseteq \cap_{m=1}^\infty \cup_{n=m}^\infty\big(\cap_{i=1}^{\log_2(n)}H_{n+i}\big)$

**My attempt**

In my understanding, either one of these two cases:

- Both implications hold, but only the application of Borel-Cantelli on the former can be extended on the whole subsequence, while the application of Borel-Cantelli on the latter cannot.
- The former implication holds, while the second does not.

Note that this is relevant because both $\cap_{i=1}^{\log_2(n\log_2(n^2))}H_{n\log_2(n^2)+i}$ and $\cap_{i=1}^{\log_2(n^2)}H_{n^2+i}$ provide independent sequences of events (as $n$ varies), and

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb{P}\bigl\{\cap_{i=1}^{\log_2(n\log_2(n^2))}H_{n\log_2(n^2)+i} \bigr\}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2n\log_2(n)}=+\infty \Rightarrow \mathbb{P}\bigl\{ \limsup_n\cap_{i=1}^{\log_2(n\log_2(n^2))}H_{n\log_2(n^2)+i}\bigr\}=1$ by Borel-Cantelli

while

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb{P}\bigl\{\cap_{i=1}^{\log_2(n^2)}H_{n^2+i} \bigr\}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\big(\frac1n\big)^2<\infty \Rightarrow \mathbb{P}\bigl\{ \limsup_n\cap_{i=1}^{\log_2(n^2)}H_{n^2+i}\bigr\}=0$ again by Borel-Cantelli

which seems to be contradictory if both the implications above hold.

The only thing I can say about them is that the former implication might hold as $\log_2(n\log_2(n^2)) \sim \big(\log_2(n)\big)$ as $n\rightarrow +\infty$, while the latter might not, as $\frac{\log_2(n^2)}{\log_2(n)}=2 \; \forall n\geq 1$. I cannot add more.

Alternatively

Both implications hold, but the application of the Borel-Cantelli lemma on the second subsequence cannot be extended to the whole sequence, since $\frac{\log_2(n^2)}{\log_2(n)}=2 \neq 1 \; \forall n\geq 1$. Do you think my reasoning is wrong or how to prove these? Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: What does $\cap_{m=1}^\infty \cup_{n=m}^\infty\big(\cap_{i=1}^{\log_2(n^2)}H_{n+i}\big) \Rightarrow \cap_{m=1}^\infty \cup_{n=m}^\infty\big(\cap_{i=1}^{\log_2(n)}H_{n+i}\big)$ say in words? Is it that the occurrence of a tail event implies the occurrence of another tail event?

Comment: Yes. But I have just noticed I wrote the index incorrectly and edited it. In brief, the implications are $\cap_{m=1}^\infty \cup_{n=m}^\infty\big(\cap_{i=1}^{\log_2(n\log_2(n^2))}H_{n\log_2(n^2)+i}\big) \Rightarrow \cap_{m=1}^\infty \cup_{n=m}^\infty\big(\cap_{i=1}^{\log_2(n)}H_{n+i}\big)$ and $\cap_{m=1}^\infty \cup_{n=m}^\infty\big(\cap_{i=1}^{\log_2(n^2)}H_{n^2+i}\big) \Rightarrow \cap_{m=1}^\infty \cup_{n=m}^\infty\big(\cap_{i=1}^{\log_2(n)}H_{n+i}\big)$. Basically, I am considering whether the $\limsup_n$ of those two subsequences of $\Bbb{N}$ imply the $\limsup_n$ of the full sequence.